# Executing R scripts on remote server

Tags: r

Is it possible to execute (in my example every day) R script on remote server.

I want to:

1. execute typical R script (not Shiny app)
2. Send e-mail from this app

Comment: Sure.  Just log on and run it.

Comment: I Want this script to be executing automaicaly (without loging).

Comment: Then set up a cron job to schedule it.

Comment: This is too vague. Running something "automatically" can be done with webhooks, cron, or a dozen other methods that have nothing to do with programming (per se) and everything to do with system administration or poweruser tools.

Comment: This question needs to be on https://superuser.com, and when you ask it there, you need to include more information, including: remote OS and user-level (admin-level or simple user) for a start. From there, if you can send an email with R (there are packages for that), then it seems rather trivial to setup a cron job to run on some schedule and email its results out. (FWIW, I would focus on having R email the results instead of getting cron to do it ... not foolproof, but may be simpler depending on the remote server.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a `cron` job. The questions is much too vague to provide specific instructions, but here is a general recipe:

First, write a bash script, e.g. `report.sh` containing something with the sort of

```sh
#!/bin/bash
Rscript myScript.R

# Add however you prefer to send mail
```

Make your script executable

```sh
chmod +x report.sh
```

Then, add the bash script to crontab, first typing `crontab -e`, then adding

```sh
@daily report.sh
```

The script should now run every day (at midnight).